# How to get the bearer token in the Visual Studio Single Page Application template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I've created a web application using Visual Studio 2013 and the Single Page Application template. As per:

[image: visual studio screen shot]

I've created my own Controller and added the [Authorize] attribute to the class. The Controller now turns 401 - which is expected since I've done nothing on the client-side to pass in the Authorization Bearer token.

My question is - how do I get this token? The /Token URL seems to expect a username and password - which I don't have on the Index page. I don't see it in sessionStorage or the like. I would presume that I have to trade my one of my AspNet cookies in for a token - but can't seem to find any example of how to do so.

I would be very grateful if someone could hit me with the clue stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SPA template, you can see how to get the bearer token if you look at Scripts/app/home.viewmodel.js.

Specifically, it is getting the token from app.dataModel.getAccessToken()

```
   $.ajax({
            method: 'get',
            url: app.dataModel.userInfoUrl,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + app.dataModel.getAccessToken()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                self.myHometown('Your Hometown is : ' + data.hometown);
            }
        });
```

The access token is set when the user signs in. As you guessed, the token is stored in sessionStorage:

```
function AppDataModel() {
var self = this;
// Routes
self.userInfoUrl = "/api/Me";
self.siteUrl = "/";

// Route operations

// Other private operations

// Operations

// Data
self.returnUrl = self.siteUrl;

// Data access operations
self.setAccessToken = function (accessToken) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("accessToken", accessToken);
};

self.getAccessToken = function () {
    return sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken");
};
}
```

If you want to know more about how this works in general, check out the this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

```
@using System.Web.Mvc
@model EmployeePortal.Web.Models.LoginModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Login</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "loginForm" }))
{
    @Html.Hidden("grant_type", "password")
    @Html.Label("Username")
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { @Name = "username", @Id = "username" })
    @Html.Label("Password")
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { @Name = "username", @Id = "password" })

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitForm"/>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ($) {

     function loginUser(token, expiresInSeconds) {
            var expireyDateTime = new Date();
            expireyDateTime.setSeconds(expiresInSeconds);
            $.cookie('bearerToken', token, { expires: expireyDateTime, path: '/' });
        alert('logged in');
     }

        $("#submitForm").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var loginForm = $('#loginForm').serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                url: 'http://localhost:54435/token',
                data: loginForm
            }).success(function (data) {
                loginUser(data.access_token, data.expires_in);
            }).error(function (data) {
                alert('login failed');
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

With the sample above, I've just called the token end point, and then once this is verified and the ajax called has succeeded add this to a cookie with the specified timeout assigned.

This example uses https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie to store the cookie.

A tool I recommend is called PostMan, it's a plugin for Chrome which lets you build Post/Get/Put requests to your API.